# get the error "whereis: 0$??: ELF: x: Error 971269271" when trying to run whereis - bash (Centos7)

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I trying to run whereis (and in some other commands as well) in my bash shell in Centos7, and I got the following error:

```
whereis: 0$??: ELF: x: Error 971269271
```

I don't really understand what is saying, and I didn't found any information about this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possibly an issue similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652269/commands-outputs-elf-zr-error)?

Comment: Saw it. My LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty. I tried to add /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib to this env variable, but it doesn't do anything

Comment: `whereis` is a `csh`-ism. Use `type`. `type whereis;f="$(type -p whereis";/bin/ls -l "$f":file "$f"`. Read `man type`.

Comment: I managed to fix this. `whereis` was located in two places: `/usr/bin/whereis` and 
`/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/whereis` , and it since `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin` was before `/usr/bin` in `$PATH`, then it was trying to run the `linuxbrew` one. I don't know what is the problem with the `linuxbrew`, but when I changed the positions, the command was working.